# Android studio new project design preview is empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I've started learning android development and I created multiple new projects with basic activity but none of them with a preview. I tried to build->clean and file->invalidate caches / restart but that didn't work

```
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 23, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check the Issue that can be given by IDE from the above `Read Exclamation Circle https://i.imgur.com/5a1eHpJ.png

Comment: Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Comment: can you please attach the `compileSDKVersion` from your `build.gradle` file

Comment: compileSDKVersion is 28

Comment: can you try to use it with the `27.1.*`, Hope it works as the 28 is still not that much stable

Comment: startup failed:
build file '\AndroidStudioProjects\Helloworld\app\build.gradle': 4: unexpected token: * @ line 4, column 28.

Comment: i mean `27.1.*` means any version of 27 not with the * marks.

Comment: Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [27.1] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

Comment: Just use any version available in your SDK like `27.1.1` , `27.1.3`....

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178873/discussion-between-abhinav-suman-and-php-user).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all your dependencies??/

Like **com.android.support:appcompact-v7:{version}**

Be sure to check all other dependencies too

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red exclamation mark on the top right corner of the preview window to see what the error is. Please post the error here for more specific help.

Comment: Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Comment: Add this to your AppTheme in res/values/styles.xml and it should work:  `<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>`

Comment: can not resolve symbol @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 tabs (design - text) open text tab and on right side you have preview you should find red warning icon there open it a

Comment: Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Comment: you have problem in your app gradle or style please send screenshot of both

Comment: project tree has a screenshot in the post now please check

Comment: take screenshot from inside to show the versions of your appcompat and support librarys,

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in **SDK Tools**, if you have **android sdk tools** 26 or later installed? or if the status is updated something? also check if the constraintlayout module are installed in **Support Repository** section in **SDK Tools** tab.

Comment: 26.1.1 is insatlled

Comment: and the other one (Are the constraintlayout module install in Support Repository section inner SDK Tools tab?) it is below of android NDK

Answer (score 0):

changing library version from 28.0.0-rc01 to 28.0.0-alpha1 solved the problem. Thank you all for your effort.